# BoxLayout не работает

Tags: java, swing, layout

Всем привет. Мне нужно создать окно, в которое автоматически будут добавляться элементы друг под другом (тест, вопросы будут читаться из файла), также оно должно скроллиться. Для этого полностью подходит BoxLayout, с которым возникла проблема. Он не размещает элементы друг под другом, также не появляются полосы скролла.
Знатоки, подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

P.S. косяк со скроллом исправил.

```
package frames;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Test1Frame extends JFrame {
    private JPanel test1Panel = new JPanel();
    private JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(test1Panel);

    public Test1Frame(){
        super("Тест 1");
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        setSize(800, 600);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        runTest1();
    }

    private void runTest1(){
        test1Panel.add(new JLabel("1123123123123123"));
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            test1Panel.add(new JButton("123123123123123123"));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Установите BoxLayout панели:

   ```
   test1Panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(test1Panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
   ```

вместо:

```
    setLayout(new BoxLayout(this.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```

2. Вызовите

   ```
   runTest1();
   ```

   перед:

   ```
   setVisible(true);
   ```

вот так:

```
    runTest1();
    setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Всё работает!